# SSIS: store user variable values in s SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, foreach, ssis

I have an SSIS package that has a user variable mapped to a `ForEach loop Container` (that reads a number of text files from a folder).

I need to get every value of this user variable (i.e. all the names of the text files form the folder, read by the `ForEach loop Container`)  and store them in a SQL Server table.

I use this technique:

In the Execute SQL Task (Expressions tab) , I configured in the following way:

```
SQLStatementSource = "INSERT INTO dbo.sqlservertable (column)  SELECT  '" + @[User::VariableName] + "' "
```

This works fine, but in the SQL Server table column, I see only the last value of the variable (i.e. the last text file read by the `ForEach loop Container`).

I need the names of all the text files read by the `ForEach loop Container`. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Where have you put the Execute SQL task? You need to place it inside the For Each loop.

Comment: I have placed the Execute SQL task after (outside) the ForEach loop container ; thanks for the suggestion; I will place the Execute SQL Task inside the container and try. Will get back.

Comment: Hello Amit,

Thanks so much, it works perfectly after I placed the SQL Task inside the FE loop Container.
Appreciate your help. I have a quick delivery, am grateful you help me sort this out.